# ¿Por qué cuando limpio un LinkedList con clear() se borran los atributos del objeto que cree con el?

Tags: java, lista, poo

tengo un proyecto que entregar el miércoles.

Mi objetivo es crear un objeto llamado Aspirante que contiene relaciones de asociación múltiple representadas por los LinkedList.

Básicamente mi problema es que, al terminar de registrar un objeto de tipo aspirante, obligatoriamente tengo que limpiar los arreglos con el fin de crear otro nuevo aspirante.

El problema es que cuando los limpio con clear() de LinkedList se me borran también los atributos del objeto que cree.

Esta es la clase Aspirante

```
public class Aspirante {
    
    // Declaración de atributos
    
    private String nombres;
    private String apellidos;
    private String direccion;
    private String ciudad;
    private String telefono;
    private String numeroCelular;
    private String correo;
    private String nacionalidad;
    private String ocupacion;
    private String estadoCivil;
    private String profesion;
    private boolean tieneVehiculo;
    private boolean esEstudiante;
    private boolean estaEmpleado;
    private LinkedList<String> deportes;
    private LinkedList<FormacionAcademica> susFormaciones;
    private LinkedList<Documento> susDocumentos;
    private LinkedList<Familiar> susFamiliares;
    private LinkedList<ExperienciaLaboral> susExperiencias;
    
    // Constructor

    public Aspirante(String nombres, String apellidos, String direccion, String ciudad, String telefono, String numeroCelular, String correo, String nacionalidad, String ocupacion, String estadoCivil, String profesion, boolean tieneVehiculo, boolean esEstudiante, boolean estaEmpleado, LinkedList<String> deportes, LinkedList<FormacionAcademica> susFormaciones, LinkedList<Documento> susDocumentos, LinkedList<Familiar> susFamiliares, LinkedList<ExperienciaLaboral> susExperiencias) {
        this.nombres = nombres;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.direccion = direccion;
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
        this.telefono = telefono;
        this.numeroCelular = numeroCelular;
        this.correo = correo;
        this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;
        this.ocupacion = ocupacion;
        this.estadoCivil = estadoCivil;
        this.profesion = profesion;
        this.tieneVehiculo = tieneVehiculo;
        this.esEstudiante = esEstudiante;
        this.estaEmpleado = estaEmpleado;
        this.deportes = deportes;
        this.susFormaciones = susFormaciones;
        this.susDocumentos = susDocumentos;
        this.susFamiliares = susFamiliares;
        this.susExperiencias = susExperiencias;
    }

    // Getters y Setters

    public String getNombres() {
        return nombres;
    }

    public void setNombres(String nombres) {
        this.nombres = nombres;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

    public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }

    public String getTelefono() {
        return telefono;
    }

    public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
        this.telefono = telefono;
    }

    public String getNumeroCelular() {
        return numeroCelular;
    }

    public void setNumeroCelular(String numeroCelular) {
        this.numeroCelular = numeroCelular;
    }

    public String getCorreo() {
        return correo;
    }

    public void setCorreo(String correo) {
        this.correo = correo;
    }

    public String getNacionalidad() {
        return nacionalidad;
    }

    public void setNacionalidad(String nacionalidad) {
        this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;
    }

    public String getOcupacion() {
        return ocupacion;
    }

    public void setOcupacion(String ocupacion) {
        this.ocupacion = ocupacion;
    }

    public String getEstadoCivil() {
        return estadoCivil;
    }

    public void setEstadoCivil(String estadoCivil) {
        this.estadoCivil = estadoCivil;
    }

    public String getProfesion() {
        return profesion;
    }

    public void setProfesion(String profesion) {
        this.profesion = profesion;
    }

    public boolean isTieneVehiculo() {
        return tieneVehiculo;
    }

    public void setTieneVehiculo(boolean tieneVehiculo) {
        this.tieneVehiculo = tieneVehiculo;
    }

    public boolean isEsEstudiante() {
        return esEstudiante;
    }

    public void setEsEstudiante(boolean esEstudiante) {
        this.esEstudiante = esEstudiante;
    }

    public boolean isEstaEmpleado() {
        return estaEmpleado;
    }

    public void setEstaEmpleado(boolean estaEmpleado) {
        this.estaEmpleado = estaEmpleado;
    }

    public LinkedList<String> getDeportes() {
        return deportes;
    }

    public void setDeportes(LinkedList<String> deportes) {
        this.deportes = deportes;
    }

    public LinkedList<FormacionAcademica> getSusFormaciones() {
        return susFormaciones;
    }

    public void setSusFormaciones(LinkedList<FormacionAcademica> susFormaciones) {
        this.susFormaciones = susFormaciones;
    }

    public LinkedList<Documento> getSusDocumentos() {
        return susDocumentos;
    }

    public void setSusDocumentos(LinkedList<Documento> susDocumentos) {
        this.susDocumentos = susDocumentos;
    }

    public LinkedList<Familiar> getSusFamiliares() {
        return susFamiliares;
    }

    public void setSusFamiliares(LinkedList<Familiar> susFamiliares) {
        this.susFamiliares = susFamiliares;
    }

    public LinkedList<ExperienciaLaboral> getSusExperiencias() {
        return susExperiencias;
    }

    public void setSusExperiencias(LinkedList<ExperienciaLaboral> susExperiencias) {
        this.susExperiencias = susExperiencias;
    }
    
    // toString

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Aspirante{" + "nombres=" + nombres + ", apellidos=" + apellidos + ", direccion=" + direccion + ", ciudad=" 
                + ciudad + ", telefono=" + telefono + ", numeroCelular=" + numeroCelular + ", correo=" + correo + ", nacionalidad=" 
                + nacionalidad + ", ocupacion=" + ocupacion + ", estadoCivil=" + estadoCivil + ", profesion=" + profesion 
                + ", tieneVehiculo=" + tieneVehiculo + ", esEstudiante=" + esEstudiante + ", estaEmpleado=" + estaEmpleado 
                + ", deportes=" + deportes + ", susFormaciones=" + susFormaciones + ", susDocumentos=" + susDocumentos 
                + ", susFamiliares=" + susFamiliares + ", susExperiencias=" + susExperiencias + '}';
    }
    
    // Métodos propios
    
    public boolean determinarSiPracticaDeportes(){
        
        return deportes.size()>0;
        
    }
    
    public int calcularPersonasDependientes(){
        
        int personasDependientes = 0;
        
        for(int i = 1; i<susFamiliares.size(); i++){
            
            if(susFamiliares.get(i).isDependeEconomicamente()){
                personasDependientes++;
            }
            
        }
        
        return personasDependientes;
        
    }
    
    public int calcularMenoresDependientes(){
        
        int menoresDependientes = 0;
        
        for(int i = 1; i<susFamiliares.size(); i++){
            
            if(susFamiliares.get(i).isDependeEconomicamente() || susFamiliares.get(i).esMenorDeEdad()){
                menoresDependientes++;
            }
            
        }
        
        return menoresDependientes;
        
    }
    
    public double calcularExperienciaLaboral(){
        
        double añosExperiencia = 0;
        
        for(ExperienciaLaboral laExperiencia : susExperiencias){
            añosExperiencia += laExperiencia.calcularTiempoServicio();
        }
        
        return añosExperiencia;
        
    }
    
    public String determinarNivelFormacion(){
        
        String maximoNivelFormacion = "";
        LinkedList<EstudioRealizado> losEstudiosRealizados = new LinkedList<>();
        
        // Creando arreglo de solo objetos de estudios realizados
        
        for(FormacionAcademica laFormacion : susFormaciones){
            
            losEstudiosRealizados.add((EstudioRealizado) laFormacion);    
            
        }
        
        // Encontrando el mayor nivel de formación
        
        int mayorNivelFormacion = losEstudiosRealizados.get(0).getNivel();
        
        for(int i = 1; i < losEstudiosRealizados.size(); i++){
            if(losEstudiosRealizados.get(i).getNivel() > mayorNivelFormacion){
                mayorNivelFormacion = losEstudiosRealizados.get(i).getNivel();
            }
        }
        
        switch(mayorNivelFormacion){
            case 0: 
                maximoNivelFormacion = "Primaria";
                break;
            case 1: 
                maximoNivelFormacion = "Bachillerato";
                break;
            case 2: 
                maximoNivelFormacion = "Educación Superior";
                break;
            case 3: 
                maximoNivelFormacion = "Postgrado";
                break;
        }
        
        return maximoNivelFormacion;           
        
    }
        
    public void agregarFamiliar(Familiar elFamiliar){
        
        susFamiliares.add(elFamiliar);
        
    }
    
    public void eliminarFamiliar(String nombre, String parentesco){
        
        for(Familiar elFamiliar : susFamiliares){
            if(elFamiliar.getNombre().equals(nombre) || elFamiliar.getParentesco().equals(parentesco)){
                susFamiliares.remove(elFamiliar);
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Y este es el código del método del botón donde obtengo los datos de la ventana del formulario y creo el objeto de tipo Aspirante

````
            String nombres = jTextFieldNombreAspirante.getText();
            String apellidos = jTextFieldApellidosAspirante.getText();
            String direccion = jTextFieldDireccion.getText();
            String ciudad = jTextFieldCiudad.getText();
            String telefono = jTextFieldTelefono.getText();
            String numeroCelular = jTextFieldNumeroCelular.getText(); 
            String correo = jTextFieldCorreo.getText();
            String nacionalidad = jTextFieldNacionalidad.getText();
            String ocupacion = jTextFieldOcupacion.getText();
            String estadoCivil = jTextFieldEstadoCivil.getText();
            String profesion = jTextFieldProfesion.getText();

            boolean tieneVehiculo = jRadioButtonSiTieneVehiculo.isSelected();
            boolean esEstudiante = jRadioButtonSiEsEstudiante.isSelected();
            boolean estaEmpleado = jRadioButtonSiEstaEmpleado.isSelected();

            // Validaciones
            
            if (nombres.isEmpty() || apellidos.isEmpty() || direccion.isEmpty() || ciudad.isEmpty()
                    || (!jRadioButtonSiTieneVehiculo.isSelected() && !jRadioButtonNoTieneVehiculo.isSelected())
                    || (!jRadioButtonSiEstaEmpleado.isSelected() && !jRadioButtonNoEstaEmpleado.isSelected())
                    || (!jRadioButtonSiEsEstudiante.isSelected() && !jRadioButtonNoEsEstudiante.isSelected()) || telefono.isEmpty() || estadoCivil.isEmpty()
                    || ocupacion.isEmpty() || nacionalidad.isEmpty() || correo.isEmpty() || numeroCelular.isEmpty()) {

                throw new Exception("Campos vacíos");

            } else if (susFormaciones.isEmpty() || susDocumentos.isEmpty() || susFamiliares.isEmpty()) {
                throw new ExcepcionArreglosVacios("Alguno de los tres arreglos obligatorios está vacío");
                  
            } else if (susCedulas.isEmpty()) { // validación cedula
                throw new ExcepcionCedula("No ha registrado cédula");
            }
            
            // Crear el objeto
  
            Aspirante elAspirante = new Aspirante(nombres, apellidos, direccion, ciudad, telefono, numeroCelular, correo, nacionalidad, ocupacion, estadoCivil,
                    profesion, tieneVehiculo, esEstudiante, estaEmpleado, losDeportes, susFormaciones, 
                    susDocumentos, susFamiliares, susExperiencias);
                        
            losAspirantes.add(elAspirante);
                        
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Aspirante agregado exitosamente");
            
            // Limpiar campos del form
            
            JTextField campo;

            for (int i = 0; i < jPanelFondo.getComponentCount(); i++) {

                if (jPanelFondo.getComponent(i).getClass().getName().equals("javax.swing.JTextField")) {

                    campo = (JTextField) jPanelFondo.getComponent(i);
                    campo.setText("");

                }

            }

            jRadioButtonNoEstaEmpleado.setSelected(false);
            jRadioButtonSiEstaEmpleado.setSelected(false);
            jRadioButtonNoEsEstudiante.setSelected(false);
            jRadioButtonSiEsEstudiante.setSelected(false);
            jRadioButtonNoTieneVehiculo.setSelected(false);
            jRadioButtonSiTieneVehiculo.setSelected(false);
            
            // Limpiar los arreglos
                        
            losDeportes.clear();
            susFormaciones.clear();
            susDocumentos.clear();
            susFamiliares.clear();
            susExperiencias.clear();
            
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al digitar los datos, verifique ");
        } catch (ExcepcionArreglosVacios a) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Es obligatorio registrar al menos: \n  1 Familiar \n  1 Formación Académica \n  1 Documento", "Error", HEIGHT);
        } catch (ExcepcionCedula ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Es obligatorio registrar una cédula", "Error", HEIGHT);
        } catch (Exception o) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en los datos introducidos \nLlene los campos vacíos", "Error", HEIGHT);
        } ```

Como digo, cuando limpio estos arreglos que use para crear el objeto, se borran los atributos de los objetos que cree.

Si pudieran ayudarme seria de suma ayuda, muchas gracias.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Santiago: Cuando pasas un objeto (un `LinkedList` en este caso) no estás pasando una copia del mismo, sino el propio objeto en sí. Si borras su contenido (clear) lo haces en todas las instancias del mismo.
Entonces: no limpies los arreglos

```
                
            losDeportes.clear();
            susFormaciones.clear();
            susDocumentos.clear();
            susFamiliares.clear();
            susExperiencias.clear();
```

Sino crea nuevas instancias vacías.

```
            losDeportes = new LinkedList<String>()
            ...
            ...
```

Para que las instancias que ya creaste no se eliminen.

Comment: Brother, no sabes cuando me ayudaste. Todo mi proyecto estaba parado por este error, pero gracias a ti ahora lo pude corregir, no sabes cuando me ayudaste, GRACIAS.